# create a top 10 list for multiple groups with a ranking in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have this code to give me a top 10 for each category

`df.sort_values(['category','quantity'],ascending=False).groupby('category').head(10)`

How do I add a ranking to this so that i get a ranking from 1 to 10.

e.g.

```
Category Item Quantity Rank
1        Milk 100      1 
1        Eggs 90       2
```

etc

Comment: That works well but also need a way to deal with ties

Comment: ah cool, I can use cumcount() to make things simpler